# controling matplotlib's figure size - aspect ratio seems wrong

Tags: matplotlib, ubuntu

I wish to create a small square figure - 1x1 inch.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[1,1])
plt.show()
```

If I evaluate `fig`, it returns
`<Figure size 100x100 with 0 Axes>`.
However, on the screen, a rectangular figure is displayed:

[image]

How do I generate a figure with a square canvas? And why the code above generates this elongated canvas, isn't figsize defined in inches? What am I missing?

(This is Matplotlib 3.5.3, TkAgg, on Ubuntu)

EDIT: Bigger square figures (e.g., 3x3 inch) are displayed correctly as squared figures on the screen. However, it seems that matplotlib applies some heuristic that makes the figure at least 2.7 inches wide.

EDIT 2: A related GitHub issue, no working solution: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2716

Comment: Seems the gui has a minimum size set by the buttons?  Pass the facecolor kwarg to the figure to see how larger it really is

Comment: @JodyKlymak - thank you, I set it to red.  The entire canvas is stretched. It also affects the aspect ratio of the contained axes.

Answer (score 0):

Found an inelegant solution - switch to a backend that doesn't have this bug.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[1,1])
plt.show()
```

This results with a correct aspect ratio:

[image]

(requires installing PyQt5 - `pip install PyQt5`)

Comment: I think the bug is still there, it just appears at different figure sizes on different backends. For me on the qt backend `figsize=[1,1]` works, but `figsize=[0.5, 0.5]` has the same problem shown in the question